# React Native : use a variable string in the state like this : this.state.variableString

Tags: react-native

Hard to explain but I want to do something like this :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        photoTree: "beautiful photo",
        photoDoor: "photo of a door",
        photoTreeSource: "/assets/tree.png",
        photoDoorSource: "/assets/door.png",
    }
}

doSomething(name) {
    let _state = "photo" + name;
    let _stateSource = _state + "Source";

    console.log(this.state. + _state);
    console.log(this.state. + _stateSource); //something like this
    console.log(this.state._state); 
}

render() {
    return(
        <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={style.button} onPress={this.doSomething.bind(this, "Tree")} />
            <TouchableOpacity style={style.button} onPress={this.doSomething.bind(this, "Door")} />
        </View>
    )
}
```

I know that doing an object like 'photo: {Tree: "beautiful..", Door: "blablabla..."}' would be better but I want to know if we have a way of doing something like above, just by curiosity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone is interest, you can do something like that in doSomething(name) :

```
doSomething(name) {
    let _state = "photo" + name;

    console.log(this.state[_state]) // it work !
}
```

Comment: @AliSao what did you tried ? You need to have a state defined like this in the constructor :
this.state = {photoToto: "", photoToti: "" }
So if you call doSomething("Toto") it will console.log this.state.photoToto

Comment: Yes , I am receiving a destructed prop variable and adding it to the component state.

Unfortunately I am still receiving undefined value for God know reason.

Answer (score -1):

you can use setState instead of creating new variable initializing them.

Comment: I don't want to create a new variable I just want to show the state.photoTree or state.photoDoor where photoDoor was in a string like : 
const propertiesName = "photoDoor" 
and use it like that
console.log(this.state.propertiesName)
but I found a solution (this.state[propertiesName])